# Is it possible to create a sharable package from a Rcpp function without other users needing Rcpp?

Tags: r, rcpp

I made a function with `cppFunction` which works as expected and now I'd like for my co-workers to be able to use it.  Is it possible to make a package that compiles my cpp code so that other users of the package don't need `Rcpp`?  It seems like the guide here http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Rcpp.html#using-rcpp-in-a-package and here http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-package.pdf create packages that have Rcpp as a dependency.  Am I reading those guides correctly that what I want to do can't easily be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you are overlooking the fact that code from Rcpp, just like code from R itself, is loaded via a so-called *shared library*.

So in order to *run* code using Rcpp, you need Rcpp installed.

Which is why packages win (again).  Wrap your code in a package, have your package depend on Rcpp, and you're (essentially) done.

Comment: My aversion to that was making everyone install Rtools for `Rcpp` to work on windoze.  Oh well, thanks for the response.

Comment: Good news for you: You don't need to do that as your Windows _users_ will just install the _Rcpp zip file_ from CRAN (to provide the Rcpp dll on Windoze).  You, however, need to install Rtools to givem _them_ a binary of your package with _its_ dll. Makes sense?

Comment: @DeanMacGregor but installing Rtools is super easy - just download and run an installer

Comment: @hadley: C'mon, we both know it befuddles oodles of people. So no super-easy for others. Moreover, you *missed my point here that it isn't even needed* even though OP mistakenly claimed otherwise.

Comment: I think the big issue is that a lot of Windows users don't understand what the PATH is and why it is important.

Comment: They don't need to. Had them the zip file of your local package, plus the zip files of its dependencies. End of story.  For bonus points, create a local repo (which is what I've done at work).

Comment: I was more talking about installing RTools - I've seen people get messed up because they don't check the box that allows RTools to modify the path.  Partially because it was too hard to read and partially because they didn't know any better.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I have taught at least 100 windows users to build Rcpp packages. I have had problems with maybe 5. (And I wasn't responding to you, I was responding to Dean who claimed it is hard - which it is not)

Comment: @Dason Use either rstudio or devtools, which both set the path for you. Both JJ and myself have spent considerable time make this easy.

Comment: @hadley I heard different accounts (eg from Romain at two of your recent tutorials), have experienced more trouble than 5 out 100 myself and am semi-permanently holding hands on rcpp-devel or here.  But yes, RStudio helps so we're moving the right way.

Comment: @hadley I did this the RStudio way and as you stated it was incredibly easy.  To be defensive for a moment I never actually said it was hard I just asked if it was possible to make packages that wouldn't need Rcpp as a dependency.  What I should have asked is "Do people who use packages that I made with Rcpp also need to install Rtools?"  Thankfully I got the answer to that anyway and as always I'm extremely grateful to the community for all of their hard work to make me look more capable than I really am.